# Automatic support removal and depowdering

Tags: post-processing

We are working with 3D-printed metals.
The printed models have to be manually post-processed. The supports need to be removed and depowdering (grinding the metal so it's smooth) has to be done.

This post process takes a long time. I did search for solutions that automate that procedure. I could not find any examples.

Do you maybe know about example projects in which the post process was fully or partially automated?

Answer (score 0):

### Two-step machining

The only way that *automatically* can depowder and smooth a metal print after its creation that I can think of is deliberately printing the item solid and oversized and including a holding stem. Then the holding stem is chucked into a 5-axis CNC mill, the item indicated in, and milled to shape.

However, this process is not faster than traditional machining but in fact slower.